# How can get SQLite date in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How can get SQLite date in flutter?

In my project, I had used the sqlite and I had written the code, but I don't know how can get data when I need to read it.

```
class DatabaseHelper {
  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static Database? _database;
  Future<Database> get database async => _database ??= await _initDatabase();

  Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, 'user.db');
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
  }

  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db
        .execute('''CREATE TABLE USER (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, badge TEXT)''');
  }

  Future<List<Grocery>> getGroceries() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    var groceries = await db.query('USER', orderBy: 'badge');
    List<Grocery> groceryList = groceries.isNotEmpty
        ? groceries.map((e) => Grocery.fromMap(e)).toList()
        : [];

    return groceryList;
  }
}
```

I had written this code and I need to got the badge data. How could I can got it?

The bage data only has one date, it was just recode the notification badge. so anytime was update it.

Comment: https://medium.com/@nabin.dhakal/crud-with-sqlite-df9254d917d0 This may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data calling the getGroceries() method in initState or  using the FutureBuilder widget in flutter.